# Database Design Without Relations/With Relations, Should I Use Foreign Keys?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, foreign-keys

A decisive situation I have come around. It's related to RDBMS especially SQL Server.

As per my thinking, any database has multiple tables and those tables are interconnected either directly via keys or via joins at the time of query. Now as per my understanding following two options come in my mind for the design of a database.

**1 - WITHOUT RELATIONS(WITHOUT FOREIGN KEYS)**

If I don't provide any foreign key relations between tables, I may not have referential integrity, but I can delete a parent record with PK and still have the child record intact. And If I recreate the PK record in parent, Again it starts referring to its child at the time of joining. So that's one benefit. But I have to update all tables records If I update Parent PK records. So that's the downside.

**2 - WITH RELATIONS(WITH FOREIGN KEYS)**

If I have FKs established between tables, I don't need to do extra coding for updates and deletes for those records. But problem comes when I want to delete a PK or Parent record only. So I will need to provide some `IsActive` column in each table and then I have to look for `IsActive` column in every query I use. And that's very nasty and lengthy. So its also not full perfect.

Now can you suggest me what should be my database design pattern out of this dilemma?

Comment: You can use `ON DELETE SET NULL` in your FK constraints (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973(v=sql.105).aspx) if you want to keep child records around. If an FK column holds a natural key that remains useful without a parent record, you don't have a true parent-child relationship and should reconsider whether an FK constraint is required at all. You don't need FK constraints to JOIN tables.

Answer (score 5):

Data integrity is the primary benefit of using a relational database so I suggest keeping referential integrity constraints in place. Having worked on databases without foreign keys, identifying and remediating orphaned data is a chore best avoided.

Answer (score 3):

First things first.  a foreign key is a foreign key even if no foreign key constraint has been declared in the schema.  The consequence of having a foreign key that has not been declared as such is that the DBMS provides no protection against inserting an invalid key value,  or orphaning a previously valid value.  The responsibility falls on the application programmer or the interactive user.

Second, you use joins in your queries when called for even if the the foreign key has been declared.  Learning how and when to use joins is basic to learning how to retrieve data from a relational database.

Third, the term "relation" refers to a whole lot more than foreign keys, although foreign keys are an indispensable part of the relational model of data.  If you are building an SQL database, the chances are overwhelming that the design is based on a relational model of the data, even if you are just a beginner.  Whether it's a good relational model or not is another matter.

Next, it's possible to declare a foreign key without necessarily using the CASCADE option on deletes and updates.  So you may still have to do some extra programming to deal with those cases.

Finally, in the case you are really asking about, where you want to delete a parent record without deleting one of the children, it's your responsibility, as a programmer or as a user, to break the relationship (maybe by setting the FK value to NULL) before deleting the parent record.

So the long and the short of it is that, yes, you have to do a little data management, and do it correctly, even if you have the DBMS doing all the heavy lifting for you.  It's an imperfect world.

Comment: When I wrote this, I neglected to think about star schemas, which are usually based on a multidimensional model of the data rather than a relational model.